# Azure API Management Client Authentication

Tags: azure, oauth, cloud, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I have an API Management resource on Azure which uses an API running as a Kubernetes cluster.
I want to have OAuth2.0 authentication for clients/applications which connect to the API management URL. I do not want any user authentication, but only want clients which want to use the URL to send a client ID and client Secret.

How do I do this?
I could not find anything related to this in the documentation.

Comment: To clarify - you're not looking for callers to pass clientId/secret to you, but rather for them to use clientId/secret to get a token from AAD which they include as a Bearer token in their request, right? I'm guessing you're asking how to validate that token.

Answer (score 4):

If you dont want user context to be involved, You must prepare client credential flow from Oauth2.0 which uses client id and client secret.

I am explaining using Azure AD.

1) Create Application in Azure AD and get client id and secret 
(https://www.netiq.com/communities/cool-solutions/creating-application-client-id-client-secret-microsoft-azure-new-portal/)

2) Call token end point of Azure AD to get secured token
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service)

3) Pass this token to APIM using authorize or from any header

4) Validate JWT and check issuer,audience and application level scopes
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT)

Answer (score 0):

No sure what exactly are you asking!

But here are two places where you **will** find a solution to your question:

- How to secure your **backend apis**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad
- API Management access restriction policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies. More specific here check the `Validate JWT` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT)